# Troublehsoot self-assembled PC

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I have assembled my PC and I followed all the steps that were needed. Even double checked them but for some reason, the PC starts for a few seconds and then shuts down. I looked online and checked all the connections possible. The rear fan (except the main fans, maybe because the system isn't hot enough), the lights on my GPU work but for some reason, nothing is showing up. I checked the RAM is also compatible and the led on SSD also works.

Can someone help me what should I do?

Here are the specs:

PSU: Gigabyte B700H

motherboard: Gigabyte B365M Wifi

RAM: Gammix D30 (16*2)

GPU: MSI RTX 2070 Super

CPU: Intel i7 9th gen

Fans: Corsair ML 240

**EDIT:**

I was able to get my PC started. It turns out that I needed to connect my RAM in a specific order (port 1 and 3).

Comment: Do you mean the CPU fan etc isn't starting up? That's a fail condition for many mobos. No fan, no post.

Comment: So I am using ML 240 fans. They come with a radiator that is used for cooling the system (the fans) as well as the CPU. The radiator is mounted over the CPU. So there's no explicit fan for the CPU

Comment: Did you take precuations to not cause ESD-damage in the components? e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=esd+wrist+strap+how+to+use

Comment: Also: Do you have a monitor (display) attached to a GPU port that actually has something displayed. Is there a video/hdmi/... port on the mo'bo' - might it need to be either disabled, and/or used while installing a driver for the RTX 2070?

Comment: @Hannu, thank you for the comments. Can you help me with the question that I've added?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by a configuration installation issue

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  You're probably looking for a forum or other site with back-and-forth conversations.  SuperUser is geared towards specific single questions that get specific answers, so open-ended questions tend to get closed.  Regarding SATA ports, sometimes individual ports physically break.  It could be an SAS port instead of SATA, but that tends to be high-price server boards or RAID cards, or mixed ports that do both SAS and SATA.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comments. I have updated my question and I'll add that as the answer. Regarding the HDD, I'll ask a separate question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I was having was RAM. I have to connect it in sequence. Consecutive slots are not one after the other. Eg, in my motherboard, the RAM slots are arranged as 1,3,2,4. So always connect them as odd sequence or even sequence. So 1,3 need to connected or 2,4